# mysqli_query returns 0 rows (weird behaviour)

Tags: php, mysql, select, mysqli

This very simple is called from an Flash Actionscript application and is intended to delete only one record.
This is a very big application containing more than 1,000 scripts and many of them use the same schema succesfully... but this one refuses to behave like the others.

For the sake of simplicity I've cleaned parts of the code, meaningless for this purpose
As I said before, it's very simple (as you can see in the code):

1. checks whether the record exists.
2. initiates a MySql Transaction (START TRANSACTION)
3. deletes the desired record
4. deletes/updates some other related information (ommited in this code)
5. if everything ok, COMMITS the Transaction

Well the issue is the following:

- If I run the script as shown in the code, after the first SELECT statmente ($query1), mysqli_num_rows($result1) returns 0 (zero) records although I can see in the Database that the record exists. And being so, it obviously cannot be deleted, jumping to the end of the script. BUT, (this is the most weird behaviour!!!) the record is being actually DELETED.
- If I comment the COMMIT statement ($query5), mysqli_num_rows($result1) returns 1 (one). This should be OK, and the DELETE sentence runs ok ($query4) but since COMMIT has been commented, the transaction is not properly finished and the desired record remains in the Database, of course.
- If I comment the SELECT statement ($query1) and execute the DELETE statement ($query4) directly, without checking if the record exists, the record is properly deleted and the last COMMIT statement ($query5) confirms the Database change.

I have traced it step by step for hours, but as far as now, could not find the reason why this code does not run properly
I have also replaced mysqli_num_rows by mysqli_affected_rows (that, for the purpose of a SELECT statement would be the same) but the strange behaviour persists.

```
<?php
function f_ROLLBACK() {
    global $messages;
    global $conexion;
    $query  = "";
    $query .= "ROLLBACK";
    $result = mysqli_query( $conexion, $query);
    if (!$result === true) {
        $messages .= "\nInvalid Query\n".mysqli_error( $conexion )."\nQUERY:".$query;
    } else {
        $messages .= "\nTransaction successful ROLLBACK";
    }//if (!$result === true)
    return;
}//function f_ROLLBACK

include ("../config/DBconfig.inc.php");

$recID = isset($_POST["recID"]) ? $_POST["recID"] : "5";

$returnVars = array();
$messages = "";
$n = 0;
$now = gmdate("YmdHis");

//check if exists
$query1  = "";
$query1 .= "SELECT recID ";
$query1 .= "    FROM records ";
$query1 .= " WHERE recID = ".$recID." ";

$result1 = mysqli_query( $conexion, $query1);

if (!$result1 === true) {
    $messages .= "\nInvalid Query\n".mysqli_error( $conexion )."\nQUERY1:".$query1;
} else {
    $rows1 = mysqli_num_rows($result1);
    if ($rows1 < 1) {
        $messages .= "\nSelected Record could not be found.";
    } else {

        $query2  = "";
        $query2 .= "START TRANSACTION";

        $result2 = mysqli_query( $conexion, $query2);

        if (!$result2 === true) {
            $messages .= "\nInvalid Query\n".mysqli_error( $conexion )."\nQUERY2:".$query2;
        } else {

            $query3  = "";
            $query3 .= "SET autocommit = 0 ";

            $result3 = mysqli_query( $conexion, $query3);

            if (!$result3 === true) {
                $messages .= "\nInvalid Query\n".mysqli_error( $conexion )."\nQUERY3:".$query3;
                f_RollBack();
            } else {

                $query4  = "";
                $query4 .= "DELETE FROM records ";
                $query4 .= " WHERE recID = ".$recID."   ";

                $result4 = mysqli_query( $conexion, $query4);

                if (!$result4 === true) {
                    $messages .= "\nInvalid Query\n".mysqli_error( $conexion )."\nQUERY4:".$query4;
                    f_RollBack();
                } else {

                    $rows4 = mysqli_affected_rows($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"]);

                    if ($rows4 < 1) {
                        $messages .= "\nSelected Record could not be DELETED.\nQUERY4:".$query4;;
                        f_RollBack();
                    } else {

                        $query5  = "";
                        $query5 .= " COMMIT ";

                        $result5 = mysqli_query( $conexion, $query5);

                        if (!$result5 === true) {
                            $messages .= "\nInvalid Query\n".mysqli_error( $conexion )."\nTransaction has not been COMITTED."."\nQUERY5:".$query5;
                        }//if (!$result5 === true) COMMIT
                    }//if ($rows4 == -1) 
                }//if (!$result4 === true)
            }//if ($rows3 < 1)
        }//if (!$result3 === true)
    }//if (!$result2 === true)
}//if (!$result1 === true)


mysqli_close($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"]);

if ($messages != "") {
    $returnVars["retorno"]  = "Error";
    $returnVars["extra"]        = $messages;
} else {
    $returnVars["retorno"]  = "OK";
    $returnVars["extra"]        = "";
}//if ($messages != "")

$returnString = http_build_query($returnVars);

//send variables back to Flash
echo $returnString;
 ?>
```

I would appreciate so much if somebody could find out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: first of all, I didn't read the question in full. but what caught my eyes is, `$query1 .= " WHERE recID = ".$recID." ";`. try replacing it with, `$query1.= " WHERE recID = '".$recID."' ";`

Comment: Are you using an `ENGINE = INNODB` outside the bottom of your table? You would need to be using that engine to do transactions.

Comment: @Muhammed: thanks for your comment but recID is the Primary Key in that table, INT(11), AUTONUM.

Comment: @Jason: Thanks for your comment. Yes, Table and Database are both INNODB. And in all other scripts Transactions are being properly processed, COMMITTING or ROLLING BACK according to the needs

Comment: All of the above symptoms would hold true if the above script is being called twice, and the call you are debugging (i.e. the one that produces the results you describe) is the second call. The key thing that indicates this is `If I run the script as shown in the code, after the first SELECT statmente ($query1), mysqli_num_rows($result1) returns 0 (zero) records although [...] the record is being actually DELETED` - this is clearly impossible.

Comment: @DaveRandom: Thanks for your comment. I also thought the same but, to avoid any doubt, I've tested, debugged and traced it for hours directly from my PHP editor (Dreamweaver) so, there is no chance to have an unwanted second call.
Note: the code shown is exactly the code I'm running to try to find out the reason of the issue.

Comment: @LELR You should check your web server's raw request log to verify that only one entry appears when you expect it to. The only other possibility that I can see is some kind of bizarre corruption in MySQL, which I would have thought would produce other unexpected results in other areas of your application

Comment: @DaveRandom: Good idea! I will check the server's log. Thanks again.

Comment: @DaveRandom: I checked the logs and everything looks normal. Access Log properly shows all accesses done but Error Log does not show any entry (since for Apache, PHP and MySql its behaviour is totally normal: trying to access a Database row that does not exist and the error is captured in the script). Also deleted all logs, restarted Apache, restarted MySql, reboot my machine but nothing has changed. Many thanks for your interest.

Comment: You say that the first `SELECT` returns 0 results, but the record is still being deleted, even though the code isn't run. Obviously that's impossible, so the problem is there (i.e., that's where I'd focus). FWIW, when I'm faced with extremely weird PHP bugs that I can't figure out, it will sometimes be due to re-using a var that was setup as a reference (but not unset afterwards).

Answer (score 0):

I have supplied this before and got downvoted. I think this framework may help you so I'll risk it again. LOL. Note that I'm hoping it helps you through your problem by supplying a SIMPLE debugging method (just change false to true ... and debugging is on!).

Use of this system is to put the setup information (everything before # Sample Execution) at the top of the page, and the # functions at the bottom of the page ... and then there are several examples of how to "use" these two functions to get data with two lines (one to define the query, one to RUN the query) from that point forward. The result with be a change in the DB or an Array with your requested data. Hope it helps. We use it every day.

```
define('DEBUG', false);
define('CLIDISPLAY', false);
if (CLIDISPLAY) {
    define('PRE', '');
    define('PRE_END', '');
} else {
    define('PRE', '<pre>');
    define('PRE_END', '</pre>');
}
require_once("../dbconnect.php");
$DBLink = new mysqli($VARDB_server, $VARDB_user, $VARDB_pass, $VARDB_database, $VARDB_port);
if ($DBLink->connect_errno) {
    printf(PRE . "Connect failed: %s\n" . PRE_END, $DBLink->connect_error);
    exit();
}

# Sample execution
$Query = "select * from vicidial_users where user='6666' and active='Y' limit 1";
$Records = GetData($DBLink, $Query);
print_r($Records[0]); // Single record return access via [0] to access a field named "id": $Records[0]['id']
// Multiple record return access via array walking
foreach ($Records as $Record) {
    print_r($Record);
}
$Query = "update vicidial_users set active='Y' where user='6666' limit 1";
UpdateData($DBLink, $Query);

#Functions

function GetData($DBLink, $Query) {
    if (DEBUG) {
        echo PRE . "Query: $Query\n" . PRE_END;
    }
    if ($Result = $DBLink->query($Query)) {
        if (DEBUG) {
            printf(PRE . "Affected rows (Non-Select): %d\n" . PRE_END, $DBLink->affected_rows);
        }
        while ($Record = $Result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $ReturnData[] = $Record;
        }
        return $ReturnData;
    } else {
        if (DEBUG) {
            printf(PRE . "Errormessage: %s\n", $DBLink->error);
            printf("Affected rows (Non-Select): %d\n", $DBLink->affected_rows);
            echo "No Records Returned\n" . PRE_END;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

function UpdateData($DBLink, $Query) {
    if (DEBUG) {
        echo PRE . "Query: $Query\n" . PRE_END;
    }
    if ($Result = $DBLink->query($Query)) {
        if (DEBUG) {
            printf(PRE . "%s\n", $DBLink->info);
            printf("Affected rows (Non-Select): %d\n" . PRE_END, $DBLink->affected_rows);
        }
        return;
    } else {
        if (DEBUG) {
            printf(PRE . "Errormessage: %s\n", $DBLink->error);
            printf("Affected rows (Non-Select): %d\n", $DBLink->affected_rows);
            echo "No Records Returned\n" . PRE_END;
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

Obviously the dbconnect.php and its loaded variables can be replaced with your existing version. To troubleshoot: Change debug to TRUE instead of FALSE. Then the query will spill to the screen and you can copy/paste it directly into your DB and see if the results are as expected. Note that for BEST results, you still have a few items to verify when doing this (some of these are ONLY necessary if the php script gets different results than YOU when you run the same query):

1. Be sure you are in the database that is being loaded into your credentials
2. Be sure you enter the DB as the same user with the same password AND from the same IP as the script that is running. This may require accessing the DB from the command line with a mysql client on the php server to be sure your credentials and permissions are identical to the php script.

The CLIDISPLAY constant is only used for executing php from the CLI instead of on a web page (makes the annoying  entries go away, but those are quite useful in html).